# Update array based on values of another array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Trying to create a subroutine where a user copies and paste a recipe into a cell, and the allergens become automatically capitalised...e.g. (Milk becomes MILK). My SA2 array just holds blank values?

PS I know I can use replace / find argument, I want to do it through an array just for personal development.

```
Sub Allergen()

Dim nr As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim sa As Variant
Dim sa2 As Variant
Dim i As Integer


nr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("E:E"))
sa = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & nr).Offset(-1, 0))
sa2 = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & nr).Offset(-1, 0))

ReDim Preserve sa2(0 To UBound(sa))

For i = LBound(sa) To UBound(sa)

If sa(i) = "Milk" Then
sa2(i) = "MILK"
End If
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you try accomplishing and I have some problems... What do you expect from the line `ReDim Preserve sa2(0 To UBound(sa))`? Since `sa` and `sa2` are obtained by default splitting of the same range, they will be identic (the same number of elements, the same content). Then, it is not need for a second array to do what you try inside the iteration. It is enough to write `If sa(i) = "Milk" Then sa(i) = "MILK"`. Then, working with 1D arrays, you can check that placing `Debug.Print Join(arr,"|")` before the iteration and after. See the results in `Immediate Window`...

Comment: When you try such an exercise it is good to return the processed array somewhere... For instance, you can try: `Range("G1").Resize(ubound(arr) + 1,1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)`, to place it on a column, or simple `Range("H1").Resize(1, ubound(arr).value = arr`, to place it on a row...